# Show $f(x,y)=\left(\frac{\cos x+\cos y-1}{2}, \cos x-\cos y\right)$ has a fixed point using the mean value inequality.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, trigonometry, fixed-point-theorems

**The problem:**

I am attempting to show

$$f(x,y)=\left(\frac{\cos x+\cos y-1}{2}, \cos x-\cos y\right)$$

has a fixed point using the mean value inequality, which states that for any $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $f: B_r(a) \to \mathbb{R}^m$ differentiable on $B_r(a)$ with $\|Df(x)\| \leq M$ for all $x \in B_r(a)$, we have $|f(b_1) - f(b_2)\| \leq M\|b_1 - b_2\|$ for any $b_1, b_2 \in B_r(a)$.

If I can find such an $M$ on some ball, and show $M < 1$, then I am done by the contraction mapping theorem.

**Here's what I've done:**

Note that $|\frac{\cos x+\cos y-1}{2}| \leq \frac{3}{2}$ and $|\cos x-\cos y| \leq 2$ by applying the triangle inequality, so the fixed point should be on $B_{r}(a)$ with $r=2$ & $a=(0,0)$.

We can calculate that

$$Df(x,y)=\pmatrix{
-\frac{\sin x}{2} & -\sin x \\\
-\frac{\sin y}{2} & \sin y
}$$

Now, I'm a bit stuck on the interpretation of the mean value inequality, specifically how to find and get $\|Df(x)\|$. If I'm interpreting things correctly, I believe this should be using the operator norm, which I'm not confident in using.

If so, I know that for $A \in L(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m)$

$$|A|=\sup_{0 \neq x' \in \mathbb{R}^n} \frac{||Ax'||}{||x'||}$$

I've tried letting $x' = (u,v) \in B_{2}(0)$ be a vector on the ball and calculate

$$\sup_{0 \neq x' \in B_{2}(0)} \frac{\sqrt{((\sin^2 x + \sin^2 y) (\frac{1}{2}u+v)^2)}}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}$$

(the numerator is $|Df(x,y)x'|$) as an upper bound for $M$.

But I can't seem to get this bound lower than $1$ in order to use the contraction mapping theorem, I'm getting things above $1$.

I'm not sure where the problem is, perhaps I'm misunderstanding the theory. Is this calculation wrong? I'm thinking, perhaps, $x'$ should be $(x,y)$, i.e. the same variables used in $f$, but I'm not sure if this is correct.

Comment: Your norm computation is a bit off - it should amount to showing: 
$$\sin^2x\left(\frac u2 + v\right)^2 +\sin^2y\left(\frac u2 - v\right)^2\leq u^2+v^2.$$
What is the domain of your function ? If there is no restriction, this is not true.

Comment: @dezdichado Thanks. Well, the function is $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, but I only need to find some $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ s.t. $f \mid_A$ is a contraction, which is why I was considering $B_2(0)$ (or perhaps I should consider subsets of this ball, if this doesn't work.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Method is like this :

When we state that there is a Stationary Point or fixed Point , what we imply is that there is a Solution to :
$(x,y) \equiv f(x,y) \equiv \left(\frac{\cos x+\cos y-1}{2}, \cos x-\cos y\right) \tag{1}$

We do not have to find the Solution(s) to (1) , we just have to show the Existence of a Solution.

OK , Here (1) gives us :
$2x = \cos x+\cos y-1 \tag{2}$
$y = \cos x-\cos y \tag{3}$

In (2) , We can see that $x$ is bounded between $ \pm 3 $ , while $y$ is unbounded.
Hence there is a Continuous curve from high above to deep down , somewhere near the y-axis.

In (3) , We can see that $y$ is bounded between $ \pm 3 $ , while $x$ is unbounded.
Hence there is a Continuous curve from far left to far right , somewhere near the x-axis.

[[ I have selected very loose Symmetric Bounds , to make it Simple to visualize : tighter un-Symmetric Bounds are Possible ]]

Due to Continuity , (2) & (3) must Naturally Intersect somewhere near the Origin.
That is the Stationary Point or fixed Point for $f(x,y)$

Diagrammatic View :

[image: INTERSECTION]

We see that the Curves Intersect [[ Image : curtesy of Wolfram Online tool ]] somewhere near the Origin.

Numerical Value : $(X,Y)=(+0.448432,−0.091647)$ : Close to the Origin.